# ActionBar-PullToRefresh exclude part of view pull to refresh

Tags: android, android-actionbar, pull-to-refresh

I want to add pull to refresh function for a listview, but in the listview header, there is a view pager, the view pager scroll horizontal and I don't want to the listview header responding the pull to refresh event, because the header is part of the listview, so I couldn't use the function theseChildrenArePullable(), any solution provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, according to my requirement, I fork the PTR project and add the function at https://github.com/yingchn/ActionBar-PullToRefresh.

and I have create a pull request to merge the original project refer to https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/pull/283

hope it is useful for you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PTR from Chris Banes :

https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh

You can set pullable childs :

```
ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(getActivity())
       // Here you can mark what views are pullable
       .theseChildrenArePullable(android.R.id.list, android.R.id.empty)
       .listener(this) //Activity implements on refresh listener
       .setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);
```

Comment: hi @Kenan Begic, looks like you does not understand me, theseChildrenArePullable(android.R.id.list, android.R.id.empty) just include some view, i need exclude some views, in my question the listview header is part of listview, so i couldn't use theseChildrenArePullable()

Comment: I see, so you have PTR that includes listView and that listview includes view pager that you don want to be pullable? This view pager must be some breaking news or sth that scrolls horizontally and that why you dont want it to be pullable?

Comment: Although the PTR is listening to the vertically touch event, but it is so sensitive, it is often disturb me when i touch scroll viewpager horizontally, it is a so bad user experience.

Comment: So the problem is vertical/horizontal pull/scroll for ptr/pager?

Comment: I just want the listview header does not response the PTR touch event